# ASP.NET MVC partial view refresh on button click

Tags: model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I'm using VS 2013, MVC 5.
Here is the content of my partial view (_Sales.cshtml):

```
@model IEnumerable<SomeModel>

<div id="outer">
    <div id="inner1">
        @(Html.Kendo().Chart<SomeModel>(Model)
        ...
        )
    </div>
    <div id="inner2">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Sales </td>
                <td>@Model.First().TotalSales.ToString("C")</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Total Discount </td>
                <td>@Model.First().TotalDiscount.ToString("C")</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is an action method used while loading first time:

```
public ActionResult _Sales()
{
    IEnumerable<SomeModel> salesList = null;
    SearchCriteriaObject criteria = null;
    salesList = getting data as list;

    return PartialView(salesList);
}
```

So far, all work fine as expected. That's my partial view is rendering fine with initial data.

Now my requirement is I need to refresh my partial view as user specify search criteria and hit search button.

Here is the search button specific action method:

```
public ActionResult Get_BulletChartData_Updated(SearchViewModel criteriaModel)
{
    IEnumerable<SomeModel> salesList = null;
    SearchObject criteria = new SearchObject();

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (criteriaModel != null)
        {
            //populating criteria here
        }
        salesList = //Getting data in list format
    }

    return PartialView(salesList);
}
```

On search button click event handler in javascript, I do this:

```
$("#btnSearch").click(function () {
...
var Url = $('#Url').val(); //Getting action method url from hidden field
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: 'HTML',
    data: JSON.stringify(SearchViewModel),
    url: Url, //@Url.Action("Get_SalesDataFiltered", "Sales")
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    success: function (result)
    {
        alert('success');
        //$("#outer").load(result);
    },
    error: function ()
    {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

On search button click, I always get error alert message.
Could you please guide me the correct way to achieve this.

I'm new to MVC. Please feel free to ask for more info.
If you provide me with code, it'd be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is that you post a json object, while your post method has as a parameter a `SearchViewModel` object.

I believe that If you change this

```
data: JSON.stringify(SearchViewModel)
```

to this

```
data: $("#yourFormId").serialize()
```

you will get the expected result.